# Close radio button after submit

Tags: javascript

Trying to keep is simple. Seen alot of script that disable radio buttons after selection, but i want it to be disabled after submit. Is it possible?

Some html code

```
<input type="radio" name="date" value="one">one<br />
<input type="radio" name="date" value="two">two<br />
<input type="radio" name="date" value="three">three<br />
<input type="radio" name="date" value="four">four<br />
<input type="radio" name="date" value="five">five<br />
<input type="radio" name="date" value="six">six<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="GO!"><br />
```

Comment: Yes of course it is possible

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: Well the biggest issue here is that i don't know javascript but want to learn something new. Is there any problems with that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#myform>input[type=radio]"));

document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit",e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  radios.forEach(r=>r.disabled=true)
})
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="radio" name="date" value="one">one<br />
  <input type="radio" name="date" value="two">two<br />
  <input type="radio" name="date" value="three">three<br />
  <input type="radio" name="date" value="four">four<br />
  <input type="radio" name="date" value="five">five<br />
  <input type="radio" name="date" value="six">six<br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="GO!"><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think i need to elaborate :) The radio button has to stay disabled even when refreshing the site, and not all of them, just the chosen one.

Comment: well in this case you need to add some state through localstorage but that is not guaranteed source of truth since user can delete the data there. You might want to get that data from your api

Comment: the main idea is in the code above on top of that you can add your app logic

Comment: It only raises more question but thanks for trying :)